# Moq checking if method is called with parameter from another call

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following function that I am trying to put under unit test

```
public MessageListDto GetMessageList(SimpleSearchCriteria criteria)
{
    var messages = _repository.GetMessages(criteria, out int total);
    return new MessageListDto(messages, total);
}
```

and the following is my test so far, in which I am able to determine that `_repository.GetMessages` is call with the correct parameters.

However, how do I test that the second line is tested properly, I need to test that

- A new object of type `MessageListDto` is constructed with the two parameters returned from the line above
- the newly constructed object is returned

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    int total = 10;
    var searchCriteria = new SimpleSearchCriteria();
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
    var messageService = new MessageService(mockRepo.Object);
    messageService.GetMessageList(searchCriteria);
    mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetMessages(searchCriteria, out total), Times.Once);
    mockRepo.Verity ??????????
}
```

Comment: It depends. If your `MessageListDto` is pretty simple (like having only 2 properties) then use simple assertions. If your dto is more complex then please consider to use deep equality check libraries, like [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/)

Comment: Could you please share with us the code of `MessageListDto`?

Comment: MessageListDto has many properties, but I am not testing in here that the objects match exactly - I am more interested in

- what gets returned from GetMessages is passed into a constructor call to MessageListDto
- The newly created MessageListDto object is returned

Comment: Are you saying that you want to test the returned messages are passed to the dto's constructor without any modification?

Comment: Correct - and that the newly created object is returned from the function without modification

Comment: In short: You can't. You can't since in order to be able to verify calling arguments you need to inject a spy. But you can't since you directly create a new instance. By introducing a Factory here (so adding one more abstraction layer) it can help you to be able to verify arguments. Shall I leave a post to demonstrate?

Comment: I started adding a factory but thought it was overkill (and did not know exactly while).  If you could post an example that would be fantastic

Answer (score 2):

As we have discussed in the comment section your goal is to test the returned `messages` is passed to the dto's constructor without any modification.

With your current code you can't do that because you are creating the DTO explicitly inside your method. So, you can't replace it with a **spy**.

Just to clarify some terminologies:

- **Dummy**: simple code that returns **bogus** data
- **Fake**: a working **alternative** which can take shortcuts
- **Stub**: custom logic with **predefined** data
- **Mock**:  custom logic with **expectations** (interactive stub)
- **Shim**: custom logic **at run-time**
- **Spy**: **interceptors** to record calls

To be able to capture the arguments of the `MessageListDto` constructor call you need to introduce an other layer between your `GetMessageList` method and the constructor. (In other words *indirection*)

---

For the sake of simplicity let me assume that `IMessageRepository`'s `GetMessages` returns a `string` array.

So, you can introduce an interface like this:

```cs
public interface IDtoProvider
{
    public MessageListDto CreateMessageList(string[] messages, int total)
        => new MessageListDto(messages, total);
}
```

- Here I have used C# 8's [interface default implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/) feature
- It can be further shortened with C# 9's [target-typed new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) feature
- If you are using older C# version then you need to separate the interface and the default implementation from each other

Now lets amend your `MessageService` to receive a `IDtoProvider` instance via its constructor

```cs
class MessageService
{
    private readonly IMessageRepository _repository;
    private readonly IDtoProvider _dtoProvider;
    public MessageService(IMessageRepository repository, IDtoProvider dtoProvider)
        => (_repository, _dtoProvider) = (repository, dtoProvider);

    public MessageListDto GetMessageList(SimpleSearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        var messages = _repository.GetMessages(criteria, out int total);
        return _dtoProvider.CreateMessageList(messages, total);
    }
    ...
}
```

- Here I've took advantage of [`ValueTuple`'s deconstruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct) capability

---

With these in our hand we can write a unit test like this:

```cs
//Arrange - Repo
string[] messages = new[] { "OnlyElement" };
int total = 10;
var mockRepo = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
mockRepo
    .Setup(repo => repo.GetMessages(It.IsAny<SimpleSearchCriteria>(), out total))
    .Returns(messages);

//Arrange - Provider
var dto = new MessageListDto(messages, total);
string[] messagesArgument = null;
int totalArgument = -1;
var mockProvider = new Mock<IDtoProvider>();
mockProvider
    .Setup(provider => provider.CreateMessageList(It.IsAny<string[]>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback<string[], int>((messages, total) => (messagesArgument, totalArgument) = (messages, total))
    .Returns(dto);


//Arrange - SUT
var searchCriteria = new SimpleSearchCriteria();
var sut = new MessageService(mockRepo.Object, mockProvider.Object);

//Act
sut.GetMessageList(searchCriteria);

//Assert - Repo
mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetMessages(searchCriteria, out total), Times.Once);

//Assert - Provider
Assert.Equal(messages, messagesArgument);
Assert.Equal(total, totalArgument);
```

1. I've defined how should the `IMessageRepository` mock behave
2. I've defined how should the `IDtoProvider` mock behave
   2.1 I've used here the `Callback` method to capture the calling argument
   2.2 If you perform multiple calls against your mocked method then please consider to use [`Capture.In`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269717/moq-how-to-get-to-a-parameter-passed-to-a-method-of-a-mocked-service)
3. I've instantiated a `MessageService` (which is our **s**ystem **u**nder **t**est) with the mock objects
4. I've called the `GetMessageList` inside the [Act phase](https://automationpanda.com/2020/07/07/arrange-act-assert-a-pattern-for-writing-good-tests/)
5. I've made assertion against the repo mock call
6. I've made assertion against the calling parameters of the `CreateMessageList`
   6.1 Here I have used xunit's assertion

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to setup the `MessageService` mock, so that it returns something deterministic and then in the second step you verify that that has been used to construct your `MessageListDto`.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    // arrange
    int total = 10;
    var searchCriteria = new SimpleSearchCriteria();
    var messages = new [] {"message1", "message2"} // or similar
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
// or similar, I am not quite certain as to the specific syntax. Especially wrt. out parameters. Check the documentation. 
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetMessages(It.IsAny<SimpleSearchCriteria>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(messages); 
    var messageService = new MessageService(mockRepo.Object);           

    // act
    var result = messageService.GetMessageList(searchCriteria);

    // assert
    mockRepo.Verify(r => r.GetMessages(searchCriteria, out total), Times.Once);
    // or similar; here you might want to check out FluentAssertions as @Peter Csala suggested
    Assert.Equal(result.Messages, messages); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from previous answers is that whenever possible, you should set up the mocked method with the exact parameters, that you expect it to receive. In other words set up the method with concrete values instead of `It.IsAny<>()`. In such case you won't have to verify the method later at all. (Unless it's critical to test, how many times a method is called). Simply, if mocked `GetMessages` receives different arguments than expected, it will return `null`, set `total` to `0` and your test will fail. Having the mocked methods set up properly, you can now focus on verifying what `GetMessageList` returns, which is the purpose of this unit test.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    int total = 10;
    var messages = new[] {new Message()};
    var searchCriteria = new SimpleSearchCriteria();
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
    mockRepo.Setup(_ => _.GetMessages(searchCriteria, out total))
        .Returns(messages);
    var messageService = new MessageService(mockRepo.Object);
    var dto = messageService.GetMessageList(searchCriteria);
    Assert.AreSame(messages, dto.Messages);
    Assert.AreEqual(total, dto.Total);
}
```